# “Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery”

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, rdbms, correlated-subquery

I know that there are questions  with this plot.But none of that questions does not solve my  specific problem.

Here is my code

```
         SELECT [fn_CAmount](SUM(IIF(Id = 2 ,Amount,0)),CurrencyId,@toCurrency)  AS TAmount,
                [fn_CAmount](SUM(IIF(Id = 5 ,Amount,0)),CurrencyId,@toCurrency)  AS BAmount,
                [fn_CAmount](SUM(IIF(Id = 4 ,Amount,0)),CurrencyId,@toCurrency)  AS TAmountW,
                FromCurrencyId AS FromID
                @toCurrencyId  AS ToId
                FROM [dbo].[fn_DReport]() 
                WHERE
                OperationTypeId IN(2,4,5)  
                GROUP BY CurrencyId
```

this is give me table like this

```
                TAmont   Bamount  TAmountW  FromID ToId 
                --------|-------|---------|------|------
                   10   |5      |     8   |USD   |USD
                    5   |2      |     2   |EUR   |USD
                        |       |         |      |
```

I want to result like this.in other words i want to get sum of that table results.

```
                TAmont   Bamount  TAmountW  FromID ToId 
                --------|-------|---------|------|------
                   15   |7      |   10    |USD   |USD
```

And when i change my code to

```
            SELECT 
            SUM([fn_CAmount](SUM(IIF(Id = 2 ,Amount,0)),CurrencyId,@toCurrency))  AS TAmount,
            SUM([fn_CAmount](SUM(IIF(Id = 5 ,Amount,0)),CurrencyId,@toCurrency))  AS BAmount,
            SUM([fn_CAmount](SUM(IIF(Id = 4 ,Amount,0)),CurrencyId,@toCurrency))  AS TAmountW
```

I  am getting this error

*Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery*.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply aggregation as subset.

```
select sum(TAmount) TAmountSum,sum(BAmount) BAmountSum,sum(TAmountW) TAmountWSum, @toCurrencyId CurrencyId from (
SELECT [fn_CAmount](SUM(IIF(Id = 2 ,Amount,0)),CurrencyId,@toCurrency)  AS TAmount,
    [fn_CAmount](SUM(IIF(Id = 5 ,Amount,0)),CurrencyId,@toCurrency)  AS BAmount,
    [fn_CAmount](SUM(IIF(Id = 4 ,Amount,0)),CurrencyId,@toCurrency)  AS TAmountW,
    FromCurrencyId AS FromID
    FROM [dbo].[fn_DReport]() 
    WHERE
    OperationTypeId IN(2,4,5)  
    GROUP BY CurrencyId
) Results
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what i was looking for.